Unity assign premade animation to different instantiated GameObject
I'm working in unity on a procedurally generated weapons system (so you can generate infinite combos of crosses, scopes ... etc), and now i would like to add animations to them.
For example, i would like all of them no matter what they look like to play a swing animation when the player is running, or to play a recoil animations when player shoots ... etc
The problem is that after some researchs and experiments, i can't find how to make this working.
All of my generated weapons have the same structure :

A parent Weapon object with my Weapon Script attached (fully instantiated from scratch, it aint a prefab)
under the Weapon parent, all the gameobjects for the parts of the weapon (cross gameObject, scope gameobject, loader gameobject ... etc)
under some of the parts, (cross and main body) are empty gameobjects for player hands targets, as the holding of the weapons are driven by inverse kinematics.

How can i attach an animator or animations to my weapon when its generated so that it animates the hand targets (or the whole weapon as it will move the hand targets) ?
Thanks
Is it possible to create an animation on a blank gameobject in editor and then on weapon spawn assign it to the weapon? Animations are proper to the gameobject animated so i dont know how to make it working.
////////////////EDIT/////////////////
I actually solved the problem, so here is the solution in case anyone is interested.
When you create an animation clip in unity, and double click on it to edit the keyframes of it, it asks you that you must add a animator controller to the object you are animating in order to edit the clip. Just create an empty cube and add the component Animation to it (not animator) and drag the animation clip you created. Then you can actually double click on it and start editing your animation. Then create a new AnimatorController and inside add a state and in order to assign your animation to it, you need to go to the inspector top right 3 dots, and change inspector mode from normal to debug. then click on your animation clip and uncheck the parameter "Legacy". This way, you can assign the created animation to any state of any animator controller and it will work. Now you just need to assign that animator controller at runtime to your instantiated object using the animator.runtimeController property.
I hope someone finds this useful, kinda gave me a headache to figure out lol.

You can use inverse kinematics for that. Ik is a simple easy solution. Additionally simce the object hierarchy is little complex you should add debug.break to see whats actually going on.
https://youtube.com/shorts/jryEIESiJcQ?si=SgwWpP9XdE_lZWmg
Hope this helps!

As i say in my post, i'm already using IK, i just needed to get the same animation applied to all of my generated weapon objects. But as i said i figured out it was just a matter of legacy parameter. Problem solved here.
